# How to get linear regression model with predefined coefficient values for the predictors in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I want to obtain a an object of class `lm` which corresponds to linear regression model for pre-defined model formula's coefficients.

In other words, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
# Define formula
frormula.predefined <- as.formula.predefined("res ~ 1.8765*var_1 + 4.4875*var_2")

# Get model object
lm.model <- lm.from.frormula.predefined(frormula.predefined)
```

The goal is to use it to predict future values (I could do the multiplying based on coefficients I put up with, but I'd prefer to be consistent with the `lm` class usage idea).

Comment: I think it will be easier to do the matrix multiplication yourself. You are always free to build up whatever convenience functions around it that you may to need to ease use.

Comment: In general, I would agree! The point is I work with an extensive framework in which it is assumed that object I operate at is of `lm` class type.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10027664/324364) then...?

Comment: An `offset`! You are perfectly right, thank you. I even found a nice function to build the formula in the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12323859/how-to-manually-set-coefficients-for-variables-in-linear-model) question.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to close this a duplicate, then...